# How can I combine two columns in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Is it possible to combine the test1 column values that are not None to test column.

I tried to concatenate but it's not working.

```
split['new'] = split['test'] + split['test1']
```

This is what I got. The values such as SSD and HDD got replaced with NaN.

`split` Dataframe :

```
       test      test1       new

0      SSD       None        NaN
1     Flash     Storage  FlashStorage
2      SSD       None        NaN
3      SSD       None        NaN
4      SSD       None        NaN
       ...      ......
1298   SSD       None        NaN
1299   SSD       None        NaN
1300  Flash     Storage   FlashStorage
1301   HDD       None        NaN
1302   HDD       None        NaN
```

I tried but I couldn't able to solve it.

Comment: So you want `'A' + None` to give you `'A'`?

Comment: Why do you need to combine if another column has just None. Removing it would be a better idea rather.

Comment: @AsheKetchum yes.

Comment: @PedroLobito It's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the `None`s with empty strings first using `fillna`:

```
split["new"] = split["test"].fillna("") + split["test1"].fillna("")
```

Or if they're actually the string `"None"`:

```
split["new"] = split["test"].str.replace("None", "") + split["test1"].str.replace("None", "")
```

Comment: When I use string accessors I get a Type Error : object of type 'StringMethods' has no len()

Comment: I think there was an errant `.str`, but regardless, removed that part of the answer since it will cast all of the `None`s to be strings, so you'll get `SDDNone`, for example. You'll need to clean those out first either way, as suggested in my answer

Comment: Updated answer. [`Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) will fill the `None`s with whatever value you specify (in this case, an empty string `""`). That way, for example on line 2, when you concatenate the two together, it will be joining `SSD` with `""`, and the result will be `SSD`.

Comment: The second snippet is for if your values are not Python `None`s but actually strings that say `"None"` (it appears yours is the former). If that's the case, you need to replace the `"None"` strings with empty strings.

Answer (score 1):

Try `fillna` before add them up

```
split['newcol'] = split.replace('None',np.nan).fillna('')[['test','test1']].sum(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, but you can also use:

```
import numpy as np
split['new'] = "{}{}".format(split['test'], split['test1'].replace(np.nan, '', regex=True))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the text accessors, df["column"].str, first and then you've got access to string functions.

Something like:

```
split['new'] = split['test'].str.cat(split['test1'].str)
```